# Returning an address of a local pointer variable to main() function

Tags: c, function, pointers, malloc

In the following example, function `func()` returning an **address of a local pointer variable** to `main()` function. It's working fine in GCC.

So, **Is it well-defined behaviour?**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *func(void);

int *func(void)
{
   int *p;
   p = malloc(sizeof *p);
   *p = 10;
   return p;
}

int main() 
{
    int *ptr = func();
    printf("%d\n",*ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes it is. What makes you think it isn't? It doesn't return the "address of the pointer variable" but the "*value* of the pointer variable" (which, of course, is an address).

Comment: @FelixPalmen print the address of pointer same inside func() and main() function.See http://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/sULNzy

Comment: what you print there is not the **address of the pointer** but the **value of the pointer**. The **address of the pointer** would be `&p` in `func` resp. `&ptr` in `main`. Of course, the **value** of a pointer **is an address** (but the address of the object the pointer points to).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside `func()`, `p` is a pointer to memory allocated by `malloc()` (or to potentially allocated memory, since `malloc()` can fail, returning a null pointer; this should be checked for). If successful, this memory allocation will persist until it is explicitly `free`d.

The value of `p` is returned to the calling function, `main()` in this case. `p` is either a pointer to a successful allocation, or is a null pointer, and the returned value (which is temporary, and not an lvalue) is then assigned to `ptr`. So, the allocated storage can be accessed through `ptr`, which is a *copy* of the value held by `p` before `func()` returned, though the lifetime of `p` itself has ended now that `func()` has returned.

Of course `ptr` should be `free`d when it is no longer needed to avoid memory leaks. And, there is potential undefined behavior here if `malloc()` fails, since then `ptr` is a null pointer.

Answer (score 9):

No, you do *not* return a pointer to (address of) a local variable. That would be doing something like

```
int i = 10;
return &i;
```

Instead you return a pointer to an object allocated on the heap.

You do have a memory leak though, since you don't `free` the memory anywhere. Calling `free` should be done by the code *calling* your function (unless it in turn return the pointer *value*, where the responsibility continues upt he call-chain).

Comment: To re-iterate, the OP is returning the **value** of a pointer, not the **address of** a local variable.

Comment: In interests of completeness, may wish to mention that - in the OP's example - `main()` (or some other function called after the `printf()` statement) would need to call `free(ptr)`.  If the malloced memory is released within `func()`, accessing `*ptr` in `main()` will have undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly valid.

What is not guaranteed is what will happen to the variables on the stack frame once a function returns and the stack frame shrinks.

What you are returning is an address to some `malloc`ed memory and *not* the address of a local variable (allocated on the stack). This is very similar to how `strdup()` works. Here's an implementation of `strdup()` taken from [here](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-186/string.subproj/strdup.c).

```
char *
strdup(str)
    const char *str;
{
    size_t len;
    char *copy;

    len = strlen(str) + 1;
    if (!(copy = malloc((u_int)len)))
        return (NULL);
    bcopy(str, copy, len);
    return (copy);
}
```

One obvious downside of this (as mentioned by "Some programmer dude") is that the responsibility of `free`ing is passed on to the caller.

Answer (score 1):

This is a valid and correct code, although bit confusing.

The func is allocating memory of size int. The allocation is done via de-referencing a pointer variable of type int.

Alter allocation the integer value of 10 is set in the memory. 10 should be set as integer (can be compiler dependent). But definitely will not be of greater than the size of integer so should be safe operation.

After that the pointer value is returned by the function.

In main() the returned pointer is set to another integer pointer. This points to the original memory allocated by malloc().

After that the de-referenced integer pointer is printed in the printf() statement. This will print the value of 10.

What is missing is the free() call, which is not the good behaviour in here.

This can be a good academic exercise for kids.

Comment: "*The allocation is done via de-referencing a pointer variable of type int.*" no, `sizeof` just operates on the *type* of the expression. No dereferencing happens here.